# How to create ribbon menu in PySide

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside

I'm trying to create a desktop app with modern looking user-interface, by that I mean specifically replacing traditional menubar and toolbar with ribbon menu, e.g like one from MS Office suite.

I have achieved some progress working with QToolBar (with QActions) stacked into QTabWidget, but the problem was, it showed correctly only when I set it as CentralWidget. Later, when I wanted to implement table (QTableWidget), it failed showing anything but the table...

Method for ribbon:

```
    def tab_menu(self):
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        self.tabWidget.setFixedHeight(120)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabWidget)

        self.tab1 = QFrame()
        layout = QGridLayout()

        addFile = QAction('Add entry', self)
        addFile.setIcon(icon1)
        removeFile = QAction('Remove entry', self)
        removeFile.setIcon(icon2)
        addFolder = QAction('New category', self)
        addFolder.setIcon(icon3)
        removeFolder = QAction('Remove category', self)
        removeFolder.setIcon(icon4)
        editFile = QAction('Change entry', self)
        editFile.setIcon(icon5)

        toolBar = QToolBar()
        toolBar.addAction(addFile)
        toolBar.addAction(removeFile)
        toolBar.addAction(editFile)
        toolBar.addSeparator()
        toolBar.addAction(addFolder)
        toolBar.addAction(removeFolder)

        icon_width = 60
        toolBar.setIconSize(QSize(icon_width, icon_width))

        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        layout.addWidget(toolBar, 0, 0)

        self.tab1.setLayout(layout)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab1, 'Edit')
        self.tabWidget.show()
```

I would like to know how is it possible to "anchor" the QTabWidget to place, where should be toolbar/menubar. I saw the layout shown at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html, but I'm not certain how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question, but it's a pity it was left unanswered.

If you wanted a *fixed* position of a `RibbonBar`, you can simply insert it into a `QWidget` container, divide your form using `QVBoxLayout` and stuff that `QWidget` into the first (that is the top) part.

Whereas, if you really wanted to use `QDockWidgetArea`s, then you'd have to use a `QDockWidget` as a parent container and place it into the `TopDockWidgetArea`, which would then be only a default position and user would be able to move it. Perhaps there's a way to use `Qt.TopToolBarArea` too, but I haven't tried.

But I wonder, if one can freely use the Ribbonbar idea. I saw some discussions about patents preventing developers from using it.